# Allow check only one checkbox and get value of checked

Tags: angular, typescript

I got at this moment only 2 checkboxes, what I want to achieve?
If you check checkbox for example - value 2 ( but you previously checked value 1 ) I want to uncheck value1 and select only value2. And if you want to select again value1 then uncheck value2.

I prepared stackblitz for my issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pr9rf3?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I want to allow select only one checkbox then disable second but I want also to uncheck this so I can again select checkbox.

Comment: why don't you use radio buttons for this?

Comment: If I want to change type for radio I can't get value? Try change on stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code:
`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  public checklist: any[];
  constructor() {
    this.checklist = [
      { id: 1, value: "value1", isSelected: false },
      { id: 2, value: "value2", isSelected: false }
    ];
  }

  isAllSelected(item) {
    this.checklist.forEach(val => {
      if (val.id == item.id) val.isSelected = !val.isSelected;
      else {
        val.isSelected = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class="col-md-12 align-items-center">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let item of checklist">
            <input type="checkbox" value="{{item.id}}" [checked]="item.isSelected"
 (change)="isAllSelected(item)"/>
                  {{item.value}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: A [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zyrsmy?file=src/app/app.component.html) for this solution.